# save formatted int to firestore for Javascript

Tags: javascript, google-cloud-firestore

I have this function that is supposed to return a format like this `2.3mb`

```
function formatSize(bytes) {
  var kb = 1024;
  var ndx = Math.floor(Math.log(bytes) / Math.log(kb));
  //var fileSizeTypes = ["bytes", "kb", "mb", "gb", "tb", "pb", "eb", "zb", "yb"];
  var size = (bytes / kb / kb).toFixed(2);
  var sizeInString = size.toString() + 'mb';
  return sizeInString;
} // This is just a sample script. Paste your real code (javascript or HTML) here.

if ('this_is' == /an_example/) {
  of_beautifier();
} else {
  var a = b ? (c % d) : e[f];
}
```

When I try to put this to firestore it returns an error

```
Uncaught (in promise) Error: Function DocumentReference.set() called with invalid data. Unsupported field value: undefined (found in field size)
```

The rest is:

```
var fileSize = formatSize(fileN[0].size);
```

and

```
function putMessage(fileName, fileSize) {
  db.collection("user").doc("document").collection('occur').add({
      name: fileName,
      size: fileSize,
    })
    .then(function(docRef) {
      console.log("Document written");
    })
    .catch(function(error) {
      console.error("Error putting Message:", error);
    });
}
```

Why is firestore failing to save the field.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Found out the problem was wrong passing of arguments between functions making the variable to fail to get the value up top